# Reduce logging of RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

RemoteWebDriver logs a lot of messages on to the console that are very chatty and these messages are getting written to the SmokeTest log file that gets published.
I would like to reduce the level of logging to SEVERE or ERROR or even turn if off so that it is easy to debug for issues.
Does anyone know how to achieve the above task? Thanks in advance for providing suggestions.
I tried with the below 2 options, but it does not work:

```
if(webdriver1 instanceof RemoteWebDriver) {
   ((RemoteWebDriver) webdriver1).setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
} 

((RemoteWebDriver) webdriver1).setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following static block right after declaring the logger variable:

```
static{
        System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "info"); 
        }
```

The first property tells the `RemoteWebDriver` API which logger to use.
The second property sets the logging level to INFO so that the `RemoteWebDriver` API will only report on INFO and above.

I am using `RemoteWebDriver` with Java and for me this was the only solution to solve the above described issue.